# onClick, clone and empty file attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When the file input changes and receives a value, i want to set that value to a tr.file_name. After that i want to clone that TR and paste it to the

Cloning works, but for multiple files it is not working. Anyone that can help me?

```
<tr class="file_row">
    <td class="file_title"></td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <a class='btn btn-info btn-xs' href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit
        </a> 
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Del
       </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary btn-xs">
            <span><b>+</b> Upload</span>
            <input type="file" class="upload" />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var filename
    $('.file_row').change(function(){
        file();
    });

    file();

    function file(){
        var empty = true;
        var filename;

        $('.file_row').each(function(){
            filename = $(this).find('.upload').val();
            $(this).find('.file_title').text(filename);

            if(filename != ''){
                empty = false;
            }
        });

        if(empty == false){
            var row = $('.file_row:first-child').clone();
            $(row).find('.upload').val('');
            $(row).appendTo('table');
        }
    }
});
```

[I've also made a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/a23ez9eg/)

Comment: You should include some of your relevant code in the question (not all of it).

Answer (score 0):

Change your event binding from this:

```
$('.file_row').change(function(){
    file();
});
```

To this:

```
$('table').on('change','.file_row', function(){
    file();
});
```

As the method change only bind to events that are already on the page when you invoke it. Delegating the event to a common parent works when the element is added dynamically.

Comment: Your code is working bether. But strange issue: on my localhost it duplicates everytime 2 fields, and on jsfiddle its working good (except file title) http://jsfiddle.net/a23ez9eg/1/

Comment: Hum, weird. Without being able to reproduce, I may not be able to help. Are you using exactly the same jQuery version locally that the jsfiddle is using?

Comment: Although blindly to your local problems, I've made a few changes, check if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/a23ez9eg/2/

Comment: It only clones the first one, afterit, it doesnt clone anymore

Comment: You mean locally? Because it's working in the fiddle. Can you create a fiddle that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You forget to clean the file_title in the cloned tr

`$(row).find('.file_title').text('');`

updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a23ez9eg/4/